# Using a generic logo to describe an entity when logo is not available

Tags: icons, info-visualisation

#### Context:

Cinema ticket booking app. App displays cinemas and screenings for a specific movie in user area.

#### Problem:

Part of the design uses logo to identify a cinema. Not all cinemas have a logo.

This is how the list looks when all cinemas have a logo:

[image: with logos]

#### Solution #1:

Display no logo.

[image: some without a logo]

#### Solution #2:

Display a generic logo for cinemas that do not have a logo/ or we have no logo for that cinema.

[image: generic logos]

#### Considerations:

- Displaying no logo for a cinema breaks consistency of the UI.
- Displaying a logo only for certain cinemas can put other cinemas at an disadvantage.
- Displaying a generic logo can misidentify/misrepresent a cinema.

What is better UX?

Answer (score 6):

> Displaying a logo only for certain cinemas can put other cinemas at an disadvantage

Well, they don't have a logo. They're already at a disadvantage doing business in general. (This would be a great point to upsell your firm's services and bring in some branding folks. :)

> Displaying a generic logo can misidentify/misrepresent a cinema

I'd agree. The logos here are an aid to scanability. The generic logo doesn't help with that any more than a blank spot would. So given the option between the two, I'd argue 'less is more' and just go with the blank spot if they don't have a logo to show. The other benefit with that is there'd be less of an assumption that cinemas with generic logos are somehow related (via a person not realizing it's a generic logo meant to represent 'no logo')

Comment: "Well, they don't have a logo. They're already at a disadvantage doing business in general." The more likely scenario is that we simply don't have their logo in our database.

Comment: @Gajus in that case, I'd say you definitely want to leave it blank. If the issue is that you simply don't have their logo, the cinema isn't going to want you to replace it with a generic version. Instead, they want to know it's missing and provide you the appropriate one.

Comment: The generic icon actually feels like it's interfering with scanning. Some cinemas provide discounts/reward points for repeat moviegoers. This may impact a customer's decision for picking one theatre over another. Not having generic icon there make the rest stand out more. If you're dealing with a cinema chain that does have a logo, you should see about asking your company to add them to the database.

Answer (score 5):

> Displaying no logo for a cinema breaks consistency of the UI.

Not necessarily, it's not so uncommon unless image is also used to keep layout in-place (it's, for example, why we have *fake* avatars in GMail for Android). In your case it's not an issue but...

> Displaying a logo only for certain cinemas can put other cinemas at an disadvantage.

It's true. It's so true that logo images on Stack Exchange tags aren't for free. You want to **give equal visual prominence** to each entry (unless you have a business opportunity to *highlight* some entries). This may be a stronger requirement than a *cleaner* UI (we can't deny that less you have on the screen and more you UI is *simple* and *easy*).

Moreover logos may help users to **quickly scan a list** to find a cinema they're interested to (for example because of season ticket, special discount or *simply* personal preference). Do not underestimate this aspect if you target mobile devices, users want to get information as quickly as possible.

> Displaying a generic logo can misidentify/misrepresent a cinema.

It's true, that's why generic logos should be uniform. Here you have different options and best is to see them *in action*.

## Identicons

First approach may be to use [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) concept (for an example just check *generated* avatars here on Stack Exchange network) also for logos.

[image: Identicons example]

Each cinema will have its own unique image. To get a good aesthetic result may be not trivial but you may use some exiting algorithm. In this example I used generated images from [jdenticon.com](https://jdenticon.com). Code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dmester/jdenticon) then you can customize it according to your own needs (style, patterns, colors and size).

Note the second column, I differentiated colors using brand color (you may scan `<meta>` tags in their websites to search for color hints used by mobile browsers).

It has disadvantages, of course, because not every user will have a nice feedback from this kind of images and they may be confusing.

## Generic Logos

Another possibility is to use a big **logos library**. If you carefully choose this library and/or algorithm to *generate* them then you may achieve your goal.

### Logos Library

[image: Generic image logo example]

Right column contains one slot with site's favicon. Scanning their websites favicon image ([video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5b8EIrg81Q)) you may read them all when logo isn't available.
If you use *stock images* you should, at least, do not repeat them within the same page. An example of this (unfortunately not something you can use in your case) at [RoboHash](https://robohash.org/). If you pick this solution I'd avoid to use one single image because it adds noise without any other benefit.

### Textual Logos

Generated images should be as much **neutral** as possible (enough to do not catch user attention exactly because of what you said). You may also consider to **use cinema name as logo** (with another font). Something similar to Microsoft Word WordArt (!!!) text. It doesn't need to be visually prominent or tawdry, pick for example what GMail for Android does when messages sender has not an image:

[image: Text logo example]

Do not use colors unless they're really meaningful, it may be brand's color (if available) but if you don't have a clear rule then it's better to don't use colors.

Try white/black on color or white/black on gray in your site design, they serve the purpose to don't make a Cinema less prominent but you should be careful to don't get the opposite effect (make them more prominent). Also consider a **square box** if it fits better your existing design.

## Contrast

One last note not directly related to your question. You're using white text on yellow/orange background but IMO its contrast isn't good enough, even if less *pleasant* black text has higher contrast:

[image: Contrast example]

Comment: I think the last suggestion (dynamically deriving logo from the text) is smart, but it would not scale. If you have 10 cinemas on the page that do not have logo, then it would start to look more like a barcode than a logo of the cinema.

Comment: I agree, however don't forget that _generated_ image doesn't need to be like an avatar. Pick, for example, GMail logo for each message. You may use name's initials (just for example).

Comment: I feel like the last example would work excellently when combined with the current solution. Having a ticket with the first letter, or first-of-each-word letters inside it.

Comment: While pretty, I'm struggling to see what the icons in Gmail are there to help with. That seems to be adding clutter for the sake of clutter.

Comment: Also, for company logos, I strongly recommend that you *not* use 'random logo' patterns or generators. That's would cause more issues from a branding standpoint than it would solve UX-wise.

Comment: @DA01 they have a double purpose: layout placeholder (because some users have an icon) and an hint to quickly identify messages (because of color and content, useful if you're scanning for a message _you know_ it's here). In OP case they server a different purpose: don't give extra prominence to cinemas with logo. Of course in his case colorization may be reverted: gray over white instead of white/black over gray (should check final result).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I would argue (would need data to prove, of course) that the FROM field is *much* more identifiable in terms of identifying messages than a set of randomly colored neutral letter icons.

Comment: However I tend to agree about _random_ generated patterns. Unless you have a very good algorithm they're more noisy than useful.

Comment: I can only agree that a _randomly colored_ circle isn't such useful. If there isn't a _rule_ to apply colors then it's better to use just one tone. However **when there is a rule** (OP case may be or not, for example a _brand color_ for each cinema) then they quickly drive reader to find what he's looking for. In OP case they also serve to give **equal importance**.

Comment: I'm voting for the single letter in a circle icon

Answer (score 1):

I'll go a bit against the answers here and say: **get rid of the logo**. You ask what is better UX, then the answer should be "none", because you're talking about a merely decorative issue since the name of the cinema already exists around 100px to the left. So yes, they may aid for better scan, but... do they really accomplish this purpose? Let's see:

## Problem 1

You don't have logos for every theater. A proposed solution is to add a random generic logo. I really can't imagine how (aside decorative purposes) this could do anything else but adding noise: it has no branding, it has no information, *it has no purpose whatsoever other than occupying a blank space!*

## Problem 2

Let's say you have logos for every single theater. Great. Are you completely sure all your users know the logo for every theater in the given geographic location (let's say London)? I know for a fact that out of 300 or 400 movie theaters in my town I might know a couple logos, so adding all 300 not only doesn't help me at all, but it would be a hell of a friction: **0 information on something I don't know!** A great example was provided by you a few days ago: you had trouble with something that (IMHO) could only be recognized as a movie ticket. How come that something that might be totally obscure is a good solution? As a matter of fact you're considering the icon for which you had trouble as representative of the theaters!

Furthermore, think on companies that have many theaters under the same umbrella: How do the logos help when you might have (say) 20 theaters with the same logo in absolutely distant locations.

## Problem 3

Let's go to design: why would be a logo totally out of the scheme? Usually, a logo should be close to the name, usually to the left or above the name. In your case, it's in the opposite side of the grid, as if it's something unrelated. So, now I may see your logo and think "well, this might be a sponsor" or "maybe a mall where this theater is" or whatever. The only thing you're communicating is that the logo is not related to the name. This is specially true if you also add some random logo

## Problem 4 (last but not least)

I see these screens, I see some times, let's say I see a logo... don't you think you're missing the most important part? I mean, what are those times for? **Shouldn't you be more concerned about the movie rather than the cinema?** And if so, don't you think that by adding it, the layout and design hierarchies will change, rendering your "cinema logo issue" pointless?

## A consideration and a proposal

Now, it seems to me that your problem, more than UX, is a design issue: *leaving that space blank*. This is not bad in itself, and personally, I consider it way better than adding some random noise. However, you can use that blank space for UX purposes. For example, a map icon that users may click to get the location, and even theaters near this one featuring the same movie, or some additional information or whatever you may think useful for this purpose.

## In the end...

It all comes to *test, test, test*. In a previous question you made, I was shocked to see that you're doing an app for UK then you considered useful a cultural reference on an answer from 1 (one) person in Belgium. It's like the total opposite to what you should be doing, so the best answer is: **no matter what me or any other answer says, you gotta test**. We're trying to help you, but we're not your user base, so be sure to **TEST**

Comment: The biggest reason for having logos is scannability (as you and others have pointed out). Do not underestimate the important of that: a lot of people prefer one or another major cinema chain. They might even have a ~loyalty card with that cinema. Therefore, they will be looking for a specific cinema and logos help to recognise it quicker.

Comment: then place the logo next to the name, makes more sense (for the reasons described)

Comment: "I was shocked to see that you're doing an app for UK" it is not a UK app. It is available in every country. We are doing a lot of tests though. Though, sometimes users don't know what they want, esp. evident in preference tests usabilityhub.com

Comment: "then place the logo next to the name, makes more sense (for the reasons described)" I don't agree. Cinema logo is a secondary information. It makes no sense to add it in front of the primary information (cinema name). Oh the other hand, as soon as person learns that right column displays logo, he is free to scan through the entire list.